# Toggle-bar div or <button>

Tags: html

which solution is correct when it comes to html5 i hear 
all should be in  tag its right?

```
 <body>
       <button aria-label="Close" class="burger">
           <span></span>
           <span></span>
           <span></span>
       </button>
      <div aria-label="Close" class="burger">
           <span></span>
           <span></span>
           <span></span>
       </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While both could work, a button appears to be the standard, since it does function as a button on mobile or interactive devices.

You can see it in practice with both [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/navs/) and the [_s](https://underscores.me/) theme by WordPress that buttons seem to be favored.

If you head here to one of Automattic's [demo themes](https://wordpress.com/theme/twentyseventeen) built on the _s framework, you can inspect while previewing in mobile to see this:

```
<button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="top-menu" aria-expanded="false">
    <svg class="icon icon-bars" aria-hidden="true" role="img"> <use href="#icon-bars" xlink:href="#icon-bars"></use> </svg><svg class="icon icon-close" aria-hidden="true" role="img"> <use href="#icon-close" xlink:href="#icon-close"></use> </svg>Menu   </button>
```

I hope this helps!